# Logical delete and create with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Country")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE Country SET date_deleted=NOW() WHERE code = ?")
@Where(clause = "date_deleted is NULL")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "date_deleted")
    private Date date_deleted;

    ....

}
```

When I logic delete an Entity in the database with the code 'U1' and after, I created a new Entity with the same code 'Ü1', occurs an exception "duplicate entry". Has Hibernate an annotation to solve this problem?

edit:

The Error when I insert a new entity with the same code is this:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates
> unique constraint "country_pkey"   Detail: Key (code)=(AA) already
> exists.

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.country(
    code bpchar(2) NOT NULL,
    description bpchar(50) NULL,
    date_deleted timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT country_pkey PRIMARY KEY (code),
    CONSTRAINT constraint_country UNIQUE (date_deleted, code) -- I add this constraint
);
```

Comment: after deleting U1 could you invoke session.flush() and session.clear() and try saving the new U1?

Comment: I don't have the method (clear()) in JpaRepository, should I have this? I used deleteById and flush. It's necessary set date_delete as Id of the class for solve this problem?

Comment: I think the problem may be related to the record id because the row only change in date_delete atribute, then, at the new insert with the equal id, ocurrs this error ("duplicate key"). But I really don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you manage the `code` column and you can have multiple entries with the same code, one solution would be to have an `id` column that is autogenerated.

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
```

This will enable you to delete an object with the code 'U1' and add another one with the same code.
You can check this great tutorial: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-soft-delete-with-hibernate/